# Why cant I align these two divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying to align two images next to each other in a footer using bootstrap however they keep appearing with the correct offsetting but one is below the other and I don't understand why.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-1">
            <a  href="https://www.instagram.com/thesmilecollective_/">
                <img src="Insta_link.png">
            </a>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-1" id="twitter_img">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Adsthelad345">
                <img src="twitter_link.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Help is always appreciated.

Comment: `5 + 1 + 6 + 1 = 13` - you've got one column too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your total column span is *more than 12 columns.*

- `class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-1"` takes up **6** columns, since
  you span 1 column and then offset 5 more.

  `col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-1"` takes up **7** columns, since you
  span 1 column and then offset 6 more.

Decrement one of the offsets to get this working.